# doctrine manyToMany SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an issue with

```
/**
 * @package Entity
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="r_country")
 */

class RCountry {
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
protected $id;

...

    /**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="RLanguage")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="prohibited_language_display",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
 *      )
 *
 */
protected $prohibitedLanguageDisplay;

...

}

/**
 * @package Entity
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="r_language")
 */
class RLanguage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     * @ORM\Id
     *
     */
    protected $id;
...
}
```

i'm trying to do a ManyToMany relation with doctrine but when i do an update it fires an error

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
>   An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE
>   prohibited_language_display ADD CONSTRAINT FK_77B02D13F92F3E70 FOREIGN
>   KEY (country_id) REFERENCES r_country (id) ON DELETE CASCADE':
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   'database.#sql-498_8797' (errno: 150)
>
> ```
>                                                                                                          [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
> ```
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   'database.#sql-498_8797' (errno: 150)
>
> ```
>                                                                                                          [PDOException]
> ```
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   'database.#sql-498_8797' (errno: 150)

this is th dump sql i get

> CREATE TABLE prohibited_language_google (country_id VARCHAR(2) NOT
>   NULL, language_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_77B02D13F92F3E70
>   (country_id), INDEX IDX_77B02D1382F1BAF4 (language_id), PRIMARY
>   KEY(country_id, language_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
>   utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB; ALTER TABLE
>   prohibited_language_display ADD CONSTRAINT FK_77B02D13F92F3E70 FOREIGN
>   KEY (country_id) REFERENCES r_country (id) ON DELETE CASCADE; ALTER
>   TABLE prohibited_language_google ADD CONSTRAINT FK_77B02D1382F1BAF4
>   FOREIGN KEY (language_id) REFERENCES r_language (id) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE;

i've tryed de drop the database and create a new one with doctrine with and it's ok that way, but i want to just do an update otherwise i ill lose all data in my database.

Is there any one who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that Doctrine generates a script to create the table with collation utf_unicode_ci, i changed it to be utf8_general_ci 
in order to change that i had to add this to my doctrineconfiguration in app/config.yml

```
doctrine.dbal.default_table_options.collate: "utf8_general_ci"
```